# Application.Quit() not working when "returning" to a scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have a few scenes, the order basically like this:

[image]

In the Title scene I have two buttons: one to start the game (goes to the game world scene) and one to quit (supposed to finish the application). This is my logic to quit:

```
IEnumerator QuitGame() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    // perform specific quit for windows, mac, and linux
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE
      Application.Quit();
    #endif

    // perform specific quit for editor
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
      UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
    #endif
  }
```

If from the beginning of the game I reach the title screen, quit works as expected. But, if I lose and reach game over, or return to title when done so via my pause menu, quitting doesn't produce anything. Aside from the one mentioned (title to game world), these are the transitions I have:

From GameWorld to GameOver:
`SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");`

From GameOver to Title:
`SceneManager.LoadScene("Title");`

I was wondering if maybe instead of returning to the title scene by loading it again, should I be keeping the title scene somehow before going to the game world, then navigate back to it? Please let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: Have you tried setting a `Debug.Log` and see whether your method is called, the `QuitGame` Coroutine run and the `Application.Quit();` line reached at all? Do you at any point play with the `Time.timeScale`? `WaitForSeconds` might be affected by it

Comment: @derHugo I actually stop time when I go into the pause menu! So maybe that is affecting the application.quit because I do wait for 1 second yet that never runs when timescale is 0, right? I’d have to confirm if this works as I die (gameover -> title), as I don’t remember right now if I stop time then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you meantion that you do indeed do something with the [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html).

> `FixedUpdate` functions and suspended Coroutines with `WaitForSeconds` are not called when `timeScale` is set to zero.

=> Note that [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) is affected by the time scale and if `Time.timeScale = 0` it will even never finish.

> The real time suspended is equal to the given time divided by `Time.timeScale`. See `WaitForSecondsRealtime` if you wish to wait using unscaled time

=> Rather use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) which is - as the name suggests - not affected by the `Time.timeScale`

---

Or - as you figured - alternatively of course you can make sure you reset `Time.timeScale = 1` and fix the underlying issue in a centralized way for all routines that might potentially follow.

Comment: Thank you. One other way I've fixed this is by calling `Time.timeScale = 1` when the main script of the title scene starts, that way as it returns in any of the other scenes I'd be sure coroutines work

Comment: @gfcf14 ha! of course that would be the alternative to fix the underlying issue in a centralized way ;)